# How do I use a python variable out of a function?

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm trying to recreate a version of "wordle", and I know that a lot people alreadyve done that before me, but I'm using it to study. What happens is that I keep getting the error

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'palpite' referenced before assignment`

My code:

```
import random

def palavra_aleatoria():
    with open('lista.txt') as f:
        words=f.read().splitlines()
        return random.choice(words)

def checar_palavra():
    while len(palpite)!=5:
        palpite=input('Essa palavra contém',len(palpite),'. Digite uma palavra de 5 letras: ')
    if palpite==word:
        print('Parabéns, a palavra correta é',palpite)
    else:
        letras=[word[0],word[1],word[2],word[3],word[4]]
        letrasPalpite=[palpite[0],palpite[1],palpite[2],palpite[3],palpite[4]]    
        iguais=[elemento for elemento in letras if elemento in letrasPalpite]
        print('A palavra contém: ',iguais)
            
word=palavra_aleatoria()

palpite=input('Digite uma palavra de 5 letras: ')
checar_palavra()

palpite=input('Digite outra palavra de 5 letras: ')
checar_palavra()

palpite=input('Digite outra palavra de 5 letras: ')
checar_palavra()

palpite=input('Digite outra palavra de 5 letras: ')
checar_palavra()

palpite=input('Digite outra palavra de 5 letras: ')
checar_palavra()

palpite=input('Digite outra palavra de 5 letras: ')
checar_palavra()

print('Parabéns, a palavra correta é',palpite)
```

I tried changing the order of the functions and the variables, it just won't work!

I also tried to write the code for `checar_palavra()` out of the function, but I don't want the program to crash/close once the user doesn't write a 5 letters word.

Comment: Add `global palpite` at the top of the function.  Otherwise it assumes `palpite` is a local variable.

Comment: read about variable scope.

Comment: @JohnGordon why suggesting using global variables which come with all sorts of pitfalls? Better use function arguments and return values...

Comment: @Julien Because I wanted to give a suggestion that would be actually useful, instead of browbeating the questioner for being a beginner...

Comment: @JohnGordon - I don't understand how suggesting that the OP simply pass the variable to the function is brow-beating.

Comment: *"I don't want the program to crash/close once the user doesn't write a 5 letters word."* — you have a `while` loop that handles that already. Did you not copy it outside of the function? If it's any help, check out [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341)

Comment: Do you understand what the error means? See [UnboundLocalError trying to use a variable that is (re)assigned](/q/370357/4518341).

Comment: Lastly, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It'd be a lot easier to help if you made a [mre]. Here, the problem doesn't involve `palavra_aleatoria` and doesn't require running `checar_palavra` more than once. Translating it into English would also help. I don't really know Portugese, but it *looks like* the program has a win condition but then ignores it. You can [edit] if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the variables as function parameters:

```
def checar_palavra(palpite, word):
```

BTW, in line 10, instead of using:

```
# palpite=input('Essa palavra contém',len(palpite),'. Digite uma palavra de 5 letras: ')
```

Use this:

```
palpite=input(f'Essa palavra contém {len(palpite)} letras. Digite uma palavra de 5 letras: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that every call to `checar_palavra` is preceded by the line `palpite=input('Digite outra palavra de 5 letras: ')`, it would be easiest just to move the `input` statement into `checar_palavra`. That would initialise `palpite` as a local variable on the first line of `checar_palavra`.

If you truly want a global variable, declare it before `checar_palavra`, like John posted